# How to deploy angular app to production

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5, application-server

I'm a little uncertain about some Angular 5 aspects. I've developed an app and don't know how to run it on production.

Currently I run my app using `ng serve` in `NodeJS` , but is it same in a production environment ?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ng serve**

`ng serve` is for development purpose. Check [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve).

When using `ng serve` the compiled output is served from memory, not from disk. 
This means that the application being served is not located on disk in the dist folder.

**ng build**

`ng build` --prod is for production purpose. Check [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

`ng build` compiles the application into an output directory.
The build artifacts will be stored in the dist/ directory, inside the root directory of your angular app.

Jus copy the dist folder to any server like [IIS](https://www.iis.net/) or [Node Express](https://expressjs.com/) and your angular app is up and running.

To deploy you app using IIS check [this](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#development-servers) and using Node Express check [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I do not use Angular CLI's built in web server for production deployments.

With Angular CLI, you can create a production build using this command

```
ng build –prod
```

That will create a `dist` folder, which you can upload to any web server of your choosing to deploy an application.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you should build your app for production using

`ng build --prod`

You'll find a `dist` folder in your project folder. This is the Production-ready version of your app.

Now you'd require a server to deploy your app. Install this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server and run using `http-server dist/myProject` (replace myProject with your project name)

Answer (score 1):

`ng build` generate production files in `outDir` folder.

To know where it is, go to `.angular-cli.json` file and see `apps > outDir` property. For example:

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "../../webapp/recorder",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

...

These files are only html, css and javascript and can be used on any web server

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction by using Angular CLI:

1- Build your project (for production mode)

```
ng build --prod
```

2- If you want to see your project in production mode before deploy it on the real server you can use **lite-server** to serve your project in a local machine.

- First install lite-server

  ```
  npm i lite-server --save-dev
  ```
- And then run your project on local server

  ```
  lite-server --baseDir="dist/your-project-name"
  ```